# Suppose M ⊴ G and N ⊴ H. Show M × N ⊴ G × H and (G × H)/(M × N) ∼= (G/M) × (H/N).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For the first part I think I have it:

Let **$(m \times n) \in (M \times N)$** and **$(g\times h) \in (G \times H)$**

Then **$(g \times h)(m \times n)(g \times h)^{-1} = (g + m - g \times h + m - h) = (m \times n) \in (M \times N)$**.

So $(g \times h)(m \times n)(g \times h)^{-1}$ is a subset of $(M \times N)$ which implies $(M \times N)$ ⊴ $(G \times H)$.

For the second part I was planning on using the first homomorphism theorem. My issue is I'm not sure what the identity element is in (G/M) × (H/N). I would think it is M x N but I'm not even sure what the group operation is for that group.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the group operation in $G/M$?

Comment: Yes, it would be aMbM = abM for a,b $\in$ G. Okay, so I think I see the operation for the group and the identity would be M x N.